# parseInt returning NaN in IE, but works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to take a date in a string and convert it to a unix timestamp int. I'm using parseInt to change the string to an int and it works fine in chrome. But IE and Edge give me NaN.

Here it is in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/padv54s9/2/

```
var dob = (+new Date('2012.03.1')/1000).toFixed(0);
dob = parseInt(dob);
alert(dob);
```

Comment: Check that your browser understands the date format you're trying to use -- `console.log(Date.parse('2012.03.1'))`. Support for various formats is almost entirely up to each engine to choose/provide. JavaScript only specifies one as guaranteed -- [`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD`](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks! It wasn't understanding the date format. changed it from . to / and it worked

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that IE and Edge don't understand dates in yyyy.mm.dd format.  However, they do understand dates in yyyy/mm/dd format. Changing the . to / fixes the problem

Comment: Don't use `/` either – it might work, but it's non-standard so it's not guaranteed. Either use `-` or even better build the date with numbers (`new Date( 2012, 3, 1 )`)